# How to access scope variables of controller in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to access scope variables of controller to directive, to some manipulation those variables and those manipulations should be reflected in the controller

Is there any way to achieve in AngularJS?

Comment: See [Isolating the scope of a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) and [AngularJS Directive Attribute Binding Explanation](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6282750) (#6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the directive itself to set up the controller, see [John Papa's Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y075) (very useful guide for writing good AngularJS code). That links directly to the directive section where there is an example for you linked with it's controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using isolated scope in directive. controller scope can be changed and viewed from directive by declaring scope in directive

```
    scope : {
        sampleVariable: '='
    }
```

and passing the variable as an attribute to the directive

```
<div sample-variable="sampleVariable" > </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating directive you need to set the scope property to false.
what it does is in the directive the new isolated scope will not be created and you are using the controller's scope.

By this way you can access all controller variables and when ever you modify it will reflect the changes in controller too.